# Is $T$ actually a group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Consider the bilinear form $q(x,y) = - x_{n+1} y_{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}y_{j}$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Consider the set $T = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | q(x,x) = - 1, x_{n+1} > 0 \}$ (this is the set of timelike vectors, in the physics sense).

Can I give $T$ a group structure?

I feel like I should be able to, because $T \approx SO^{+}(n,1) / SO(n)$, but I can't figure out what the group operation would be.

Comment: Good question. The answer is that quotient cannot be given a group structure in any meaningful way because $SO(n)$ is not a normal subgroup (at least I don't think it's normal).

Comment: *(this is the set of timelike vectors, in the physics sense)* What? It is only a very small set of timelike vectors. They are the timelike vectors lying on a particular half of of a particular surface. Projectively speaking that could be considered a cross section of representatives, I guess.

Comment: Well, you can always put a group structure on any set. If $X$ is infinite then (under the Axiom of Choice) there's a bijection $X\to\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{Z}$ which yields the group structure on $X$. But I assume you want it to have some additional properties?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking about is a way to perform addition on velocities in special relativity with $n$ spatial coordinates. From what I gather from a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) on the subject, there exists a, supposedly natural, way to perform such an addition, but at least for $n=3$ it is neither commutative nor associative, so in particular this does not give a group structure. It would seem that the phenomenon of Thomas precession reflects that fact that one cannot separate out a subgroup of "pure translations" in the Lorentz group. Which mathematically no doubt is related to $SO(n)$ not being normal in $SO^+(n,1)$.